# When I run the client first time it server shows the output... second time when I run client, server doesn't does not show output

Tags: java, sockets, http

Client side code is

```
try {
    URL url=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:7655");
    HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.connect();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    writer.println("Hello");

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    connection.getResponseCode();
    connection.disconnect();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname");
}
```

Server Side code is

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket echoServer = null;
    String line;
    DataInputStream is = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;

    try {
        echoServer = new ServerSocket(7655);
        clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
        while (true) { 
            is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());         
            System.out.println("inside");
            line = is.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }finally{
        is.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

When I run the client first time it server shows the output... second time when I run client, server doesn't show output. Is there some mistake in the code?

If I am not givng "Connection.getResponseCode" in the end server side receives null and shows null on console. Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is exactly designed that way.
You need to make use of multithreading in the server side on thread accepts all connection the other is your DataInputStream thread.

How i did this... i have a class all by it's self with getters and setters, and is only used for information or arrays that needed between threads. And in your main run the 2 threads that will always accept connections and read every connections.